# What widget is QtWidgets.QWidget() returning?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I am trying to learn PyQt to develop a GUI for viewing images. I found some code that looked like It could be easily converted to fit my use case. Figured going line by line to check the logic would help me understand PyQt.

I am getting stuck at this line in the following class

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QFileDialog

class Ui_MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, imgs_path,masks_path, pred_path, study):
        super(Ui_MainWindow, self).__init__()
        # sets up ui
        self.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        self.resize(1440, 1000)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        ....
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
```

The line which goes `self.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)`, what exactly is being set as the central widget? I tried to look at the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide6/QtWidgets/QWidget.html) but wasn't able to understand what was being set as the central widget. It looks like `QtWidgets.QtWidget()` is just a class containing methods for user interface?

The tutorial I was following introduced `self.centralwidget` in the context of setting it to some type of widget like `QtWidgets.Qlabel()` etc, so I am not sure what is actually being set as the central widget in this case.

Comment: `QWidget` is just a generic widget, with no predefined behavior.  You could give it content by adding child widgets, or by handling paint events to draw something into the widget.

Comment: I would suggest trying qtdesigner. It can help you figure out what are you creating (in my case it did). Btw you can imagine QWidget as an empty frame where you can insert other objects like labels button etc..
https://build-system.fman.io/qt-designer-download

Comment: I voted to reopen, as the question is not only about the role of a central widget, but what a QWidget is *and* its usage for the central widget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to explain it to you visually:

[image]

In the picture, you can see the main frame, your `QtWidgets.QMainWindow` which, in this case, is the parent container to all the objects you'll place in your UI.
Then you have that highlighted rectangle in the middle, which is actually a `QtWidgets.QWidget()`. The fact that you are setting it as `Centralwidget` I think is more of a positional constrain/indication. In turn, `QtWidgets.QWidget()` can contains other elements (even another `QtWidgets.QWidget()` for example).

Comment: Note that in Designer the central widget is created by default (and cannot be changed, if not by promotion), so what you're showing is actually a widget that is child of the central widget; having a central widget is not just a choice, but almost a requirement (in fact, Qt docs suggests that *not* setting a central widget for QMainWindow is not supported)

Comment: @musicamante yes you are right. I thought his main doubt was more about what a Qwidget is in concrete. This seems a good way to understand it imo.

Comment: Seeing it in this way is indeed useful. So you're basically setting a blank widget as the central widget, because its a requirement to have one. I didnt know that, thanks

Comment: @visual360 happy to help! happier if you upvote or accept ;D

Comment: Done, altho it's strange I can't publicly upvote on my own question...

Comment: @visual360 some reputation is required to gain certain authorizations, but in anycase upvoting your own question is almost pointless. Besides that, there are other reasons behind setting the central widget, unfortunately your question was closed just seconds before I posted my answer that covered those aspects too. If you get enough attention, maybe it will be opened again.

Comment: I didnt read back what i typed... I meant to say its 'strange i cant publicly upvote the ANSWER to my own question'. I understand the point about reputation. Can you not send the other reasons via comments? Or are the other reasons too long for comment format